# Converting SpatVector to sf or sp

Tags: r, r-raster

Is there a straightforward way to convert polygonal `SpatVector` class objects (from the `terra` library) to either simple features or `SpatialPolygonsDataFrames`?

Comment: You might get better answers if you describe what (if anything) you've tried so far.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v
#class       : SpatVector 
#geometry    : polygons 
#elements    : 12
#extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#names       : ID_1, NAME_1, ID_2, NAME_2, AREA
```

You can create an `sf` object from a `SpatVector` like this:

```
s <- sf::st_as_sf(v)
```

To go in the other direction to create `SpatVector` from an `sf`:

```
vv <- vect(s)
```

To create an `sp` object from a `SpatVector`:

```
library(raster)
x <- as(v, "Spatial")
x
#class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
#features    : 12 
#extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#variables   : 5
#names       : ID_1,     NAME_1, ID_2,   NAME_2, AREA 
#min values  :    1,   Diekirch,    1, Capellen,   76 
#max values  :    3, Luxembourg,   12,    Wiltz,  312
```

And you can create a SpatVector from a Spatial* vector type object with

```
vs <- vect(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. I currently have `sp` version verson 1.4.4 and `terra` version 0.9.6 (installed from Github), but when I try `as(v, "Spatial")` I get an error indicating `Error in .local(obj, ...) : cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix`

Comment: That is a bug in CRAN `raster` --- I will send them an updated version today

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim : it works for me with the CRAN version. You may need to update the raster package as well for this to work properly

Comment: @RobertHijmans, updating all packages corrected this issue.

Comment: @RobertHijmans the bug has resurfaced with package versions: terra 1.2.10
raster 3.4.10
sf 0.9.8
spatial 7.3.14

Comment: I have updated the answer and it should work now.

Comment: what about going from `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` to `SpatVector`? Is that possible?

Comment: @HoneyBear: Just do `vect(SPDF)`.